# Category list not returning all related entries

Tags: categories

Here's my code:

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('artistLocation') %}

    {% set entryCount = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).total() %}

    {% if entryCount %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }} ({{ entryCount }})</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

For some reason, this is only returning the first six categories with entries associated.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2ut7j48acnq1g0/Screenshot%202016-05-06%2010.49.34.png?dl=0

Nothing in the error logs that are shedding any light on it for me.

Any ideas would be awesome!

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your database, but are you sure you actually have more than 6 `artistLocation` categories assigned to various entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many categories do you have in that locations group? A criteria model returns the first 100 elements only by default, so any category falling behind that wouldn't be listed, no matter if there's related entries or not.

Add `limit(null)` to your `craft.categories` criteria model to make it return all categories.